# Which is the good way to share Database Data to other Team?- Rest API or Database Direct Access

Tags: database, rest

I want to share database data to other team for their real time prediction/calculation.I don't know whats the best way to share the data -> **Rest Api or Direct Read Database Access**.If anyone have prior experience on this, please help me here.

Answer (score 0):

It always depends case to case. For example, if the other team is in same company and you're sure that your data and database schema is in safe hands then then you should give them `Read Only Access` only.

But if that is not case, you should write APIs and expose only require data with them. By following this approach, your database structure will be not visible to them.